# how to use different tabhosts for different layouts in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I know how to write tab host,but here the scenario is little bit different
I have a screen ,in that 2 tabs are there 1.ABC 2.XYZ
when ever we click on the XYZ tab next page onwords we need to display 4 other tabs P,Q,R,S
how to set tabhosts to meet the above criteria please specify any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add that method into your TabActivity:

```
    private void addTab(String name, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(name);

        spec.setIndicator(name);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

    public void addMyFourNewTabs()
    {
        addTab("P", PActivity.class);
        addTab("Q", QActivity.class);
        addTab("R", RActivity.class);
        addTab("S", SActivity.class);
    }
```

In your Activity where you want to create the new Tabs:

```
((TabActivity) getParent()).getTabHost().addMyFourNewTabs();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create two classes that extends TabActivity

First that contains

```
1.ABC
2.XYZ
```

Second contains

```
1.P
2.Q
3.R
4.S
```

Now you have to call startActivity with the Intent of second TabActivity inside `onTabChanged()` so when Tab XYZ is selected open the second TabActivity.